# React-testing-library with connected react router together

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-testing-library, connected-react-router

I am trying to test a workflow with a React app. When all fields are filled within a workflow step, the user is able to click the "next" button. This action registers a state in a reducer and changes the URL to go to the next workflow step.

[According to the RTL documentation] [1](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router), I wrap my component under test in a store provider and a connected router using this function:

```
export const renderWithRedux = (ui: JSX.Element, initialState: any = {}, route: string = "/") => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const root = reducer({}, { type: "@@INIT" })
  const state = mergeDeepRight(root, initialState)

  const store = createStoreWithMiddleWare(reducer, state)
  const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route]})

  const Wrapper = ({ children }: any) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>{children}</ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  )
  return {
    ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper }),
    // adding `store` to the returned utilities to allow us
    // to reference it in our tests (just try to avoid using
    // this to test implementation details).
    history,
    store
  }
}
```

Unlike in the documentation, I am using `connected-react-router`, not `react-router-dom`, but I've seen some people using `connected-react-router` with RTL on the web, so I don't think the problem comes from here.

The component under test is wrapped in a `withRouter` function, and I refresh the URL via the connected react router `push` function, dispatching via the redux `connect`function:

```
export default withRouter(
  connect<any, any, any>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(View)
)
```

Everything work well in production, but the page doesn't refresh when I fire a `click` event on the "next" button. Here is the code of my test (to make it easier to read for you, I have filled all field and enable the "next" button):

```
    const {
      container,
      queryByText,
      getAllByPlaceholderText,
      getByText,
      debug,
      getAllByText
    } = renderWithRedux(<Wrapper />, getInitialState(), "/workflow/EXAC")

    await waitForElement(
      () => [getByText("supplierColumnHeader"), getByText("nextButton")],
      { container }
    )

    fireEvent.click(getByText("nextButton"))

    await waitForElement(
      () => [getByText("INTERNAL PARENT"), getByText("EXTERNAL PARENT")],
      { container }
    )
```

Any clue as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: Hey @ViGrad, found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There's insufficient information in your question to figure out exactly what's going on, but this is a big clue:

> When all fields are filled withing a workflow step, user is able to
> click to the "next" button. This action registers a state in a reducer
> and changes the URL to go to the next workflow step.

Clicking the button changes the URL.  For this to work, the corresponding `Route` needs to be rendered within the `ConnectedRouter` in a functional manner, ideally, in the same manner used in the application, which works. Based on the following, I'm guessing that you're not rendering the `Route` required for the expected page to be rendered:

> The component under test is wrapped in a withRouter function, and I
> refresh the URL via the connected react router push function,
> dispatching via the redux connectfunction

From what I can tell, your `renderWithRedux` utility is rendering the provided element within a redux `Provider` and a `ConnectedRouter`.  This means the element you provide:

- should be working in context of the redux store, so dispatching actions should work, assuming that the `store` used in your tests is functionally the same as the one used in your working application.
- should respond to route changes, assuming that you're also rendering the `Route` that corresponds to the URL change under test, ideally in the same way it does in your working application.

If whatever you're rendering isn't actually rendering the `Route` that corresponds to your URL change, nothing will happen in the DOM.  Either the `history` object returned from your render utility will be updated with an additional entry or JSDOM's `window.location` will be updated.

You can assert on changes to `history` or `window.location` if need be, but that is less than ideal, as testing library recommends testing the user experience, rather than technical/implementation details:

```
fireEvent.click(getByText("nextButton"));
expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/step-two');
```